# Object into an array then return a component - React JS Application

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

Evening fellow developers,

I've rewrote a React JS application, but I've just hit a brick wall.

I have a form which adds some data to a database, specifically Firebase googles very own cloud based database solution. However, now I'm trying to fetch the data and render the components below but I'm sure how to do this.

What I receive from Firebase as a response :

[Response From Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNCom.jpg)

Currently I'm just logging the response to show I do receive a response, I have set the response to an empty state. On render it gets set to the response from the server.

I want to be able to now convert the objects into an array which can then return an array of responses. The array will then be looped through and transformed into components which will get rendered below as I specified above.

Can someone assist me with this task as I'm very unsure how to accomplish this task. I will appreciate any responses to my question.

Github Link: https://github.com/AlexMachin1997/React-JS-Contact-Book
What i have so far:

componentDidMount () {

```
  axios.get("/contact.json")

  .then(response => {
      this.setState({
          contactsArray: response.data.person
      })
      console.log(this.state.contactsArray)
  })

  //Any Errors The Error State Is Set To True
  .catch (error => {
  console.log(error)
  })
```

}

Comment: It would be better paste the response here with code block and show us what you tried up to now? So, you just want to render the response objects, yes?

Comment: Ive added the block of code to show the code block :)

Comment: I meant the response itself. What you show us how you get the data and set the state. This is OK. Doesn't my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1):

To convert the response object into an array you can use `Object.keys` or `Object.values`

```
Object.values(firebaseResponse);
```

or

```
Object.keys(firebaseResponse).map((x) => { 
    // additional transformation
    return x;
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Answer (score 0):

You can use Object.values or Object.keys to get an array from your object. But Object.keys is more suitable if you don't have unique id's in your `persons` object since you will need a key to iterate a JSX prop or your component. If response is in your root state:

```
  render() {
    const obj = this.state;
    return (
        Object.keys( obj ).map( objKey =>
        (
          <div key={objKey}>
              <p>Name: {obj[objKey].persons.name}</p>
              <p>Email: {obj[objKey].persons.email}</p>
              <p>Phone: {obj[objKey].persons.phone}</p>
          </div>
        )
      )
    );
  }
```

or pass it to another component:

```
render() {
    const obj = this.state;
    return (
      Object.keys(obj).map(objKey =>
          <Person obj={obj} objKey={objKey} />
      )
    );
  }
```

With Object.values this will be slightly cleaner but you should use something unique for your key. I've chosen email property since emails are unique.

```
  render() {
    const obj = this.state;
    return (
      Object.values(obj).map(value =>
        (
          <div key={value.persons.email}>
            <p>Name: {value.persons.name}</p>
            <p>Email: {value.persons.email}</p>
            <p>Phone: {value.persons.phone}</p>
          </div>
        )
      )
    );
  }
```

or again with a component:

```
render() {
    const obj = this.state;
    return (
      Object.values(obj).map(value =>
          <Person value={value} />
      )
    );
  }
```

Comment: Sorry to everyone who response to this question . I completely forgot I posted the question here. I did find a solution to my problem in the end I just did this instead

Comment: const arrayOfComponents = [];

    for(let key in this.state.contactsArray) {
      arrayOfComponents.push({
          id: key,
          config: this.state.contactsArray[key]
      });
    }

    console.log(arrayOfComponents)

    let contacts = (
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          {arrayOfComponents.map(component => (
           <Contacts key={component.id} component={component.config.persons} /> 
          ))}
        </div> 
      </div>
    )

Comment: But I'm now facing an issue when I update the child from the parent It doesn't re-render.